# Set default icon theme to cupertino flutter appbar

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

The app that im building requires me to have an AppBar with a leading back button. However I prefer the cupertino back button(iOS-style) for the leading icon instead of the default back button for android. I am aware that I can manually change the leading button of each AppBar by using an iconButton but i was wondering if there is any easy way to do this like a theme. Any help appreciated.

Comment: When you run your app is on android devive the backbutton icon is like <- and when you app run on iOS device the backbutton icon is like < , I think is set to be on device or platform

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `MaterialApp` as your root widget you can use `CupertinoApp` to do the same, assuming that the above changing of the AppBar is needed for each screen in your app. This will automatically set the icon as you require

Here is a simple example to help you

Root Widget or starting point of the app

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const CupertinoApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

Then using a `CupertinoPageScaffold` where you want the `CupertinoNavigationBar` (I mean your appbar with ios icons) with the chevron icon like ios

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        // Try removing opacity to observe the lack of a blur effect and of sliding content.
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true // This will decide if the leading icon comes in by default
        backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey.withOpacity(0.5),
        middle: const Text('Sample Code'),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(height: 50, color: CupertinoColors.systemRed),
          Container(height: 50, color: CupertinoColors.systemGreen),
          Container(height: 50, color: CupertinoColors.systemBlue),
          Container(height: 50, color: CupertinoColors.systemYellow),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using cupertino app? I want my app to look and feel the same. Just need to change the leading back icon button for all pages.

Comment: Then the only way is setting the `leading` property manually for each `AppBar` that you will use

Comment: I would suggest implementing a customAppBar widget, using a row and then using the same app bar across all your pages if that is not acceptable to you though. I mean there is nothing that can save you the hard work of writing the same thing across all your pages xP. Also please mark this answer as accepted if it helped you, who wouldn't like those reputation points

Answer (score 0):

Facing a relatively similar problem I used the `builder` property, which it should work with any `App` like :

```
CupertinoApp(
      builder: (_, child) => IconTheme(
        data: IconThemeData(
          size: 15,
          color: const Color(0xffffffff),
        ),
        child: child,
      ),
)
```

My problem was with the default icon color and size but you can use `AppBarTheme` or any similar widget to achieve what you want.

This may help you override default value with majority of the lacking theme delegates when working with the cupertino family (It's not yet mature like the material but I can see the constant and rapid effort and the future of it).